# How to wrap long text in spinner items in codenameone?

Tags: spinner, codenameone

In below image item names are getting clipped off. so i want to display spinner items in multi lines in codenameone. for that I have created custom picker and  changed extension from `Button` to `SpanButton` and it is effecting to selected item but not drop down item.

[image]

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Spinner is deprecated for a reason. It is based on the `List` class which is stateless and derives its concepts from Swing. That means the same component object is used both for all selected values and another component is used for all unselected values.

If your first element that was unselected didn't span this will behave in the same way for all the following elements. That's just how a lists work.

Comment: Thanks shai.. is there any alternative to wrap the text in picker items?

Comment: or is there any alternative for spinner/picker to show drop down item completely?

Comment: The alternative is to use a Container with a list of elements. You can show it as a popup dialog so it appears right below see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html